# d3 v4 plugin - How to require other d3 plugins?

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, npm, rollupjs

I'm trying to build a d3 v4 plugin following https://bost.ocks.org/mike/d3-plugin/ - the ultimate goal is to be able npm install the plugin and use it in an Angular 2/4 component.

My repo is here:

https://github.com/denisemauldin/d3-timeline

Examples:

https://denisemauldin.github.io/d3-timeline/examples/example.html

I'm running into issues trying to include other d3 requirements.  The above doesn't include examples of how to use other d3 components.
I need to use `d3.timeFormat`, `d3.timeHour`, `d3.scaleOrdinal`, `d3.schemeCategory`, `d3.mouse`, `d3.select`, `d3.axisTop`, `d3.axisBottom`, and `d3.scaleLinear`.

These come from `d3-axis`, `d3-scale`, `d3-selection`, `d3-time`, and `d3-time-format`.  I've attempted a couple of different ways:

1) Including them in the index.js as imports

```
 import "d3-axis";
 import "d3-scale";
 import "d3-selection";
 import "d3-time";
 import "d3-time-format";
 export {default as timeline} from "./src/timeline";
```

2) Including it in the timeline.js source:

```
var d3 = Object.assign({}, require("d3-axis"), require("d3-scale"), require("d3-selection"), require("d3-time"), require("d3-time-format"));
(function() {
    d3.timeline = function() {
                //variable definitions
                function timeline (gParent) {};
                //method definitions
                return timeline;
        };
})();
export default d3.timeline;
```

Right now it loads in the browser and works well, but I can't figure out how to get the npm install to work so that I can build a npm package for use with my Angular2 site.

I've tried a number of different `rollup.config.js` options with `rollup-plugin-commonjs`.  I'm not sure that's the way I want to go because it seems to produce a bundle file that includes all of the d3 code I'm requiring.  Right now the rollup call (that was included in the d3 plugin starter bundle) is failing:

```
rm -rf build && mkdir build && rollup -c -f umd -n d3 -o build/d3-timeline.js -- index.js

'default' is not exported by 'd3-timeline/src/timeline.js' (imported by 'd3-timeline/index.js')
```

If I remove my `rollup.config.js` then it gives me the same error, but also says:

```
Treating 'd3-axis' as external dependency
Treating 'd3-scale' as external dependency
Treating 'd3-selection' as external dependency
Treating 'd3-time' as external dependency
Treating 'd3-time-format' as external dependency
```

So, how do I update the `src/timeline.js` file to export default so that I can use it with `npm install d3-timeline` for use in Angular and also be able to be used in a browser?  Alternately, how do I configure rollup to make the current `src/timeline.js` file work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think part of the problem is that you should be importing the d3 dependencies in your `src/timeline.js` file, not in your `rollup.config.js` file.

You also need to export your timeline function from `src/timeline.js` file, instead of wrapping it in an IIFE.

for example:

```
// src/timeline.js
import { axisBottom, axisTop } from 'd3-axis';
import { timeFormat } from 'd3-time-format';
import { timeHour } from 'd3-time';
import { scaleOrdinal, scaleLinear, schemeCategory20 } from 'd3-scale';
import { select } from 'd3-selection';

export default function timeline() {
  // your code here...
}
```

Then your `index.js` file would only have:

```
export { default as timeline } from "./src/timeline";
```

Then in your package.json file you would need to specify the d3 modules you're importing as dependencies:

```
// in package.json
dependencies: {
  "d3-axis": "^1.0.0",
  "d3-time-format": "^2.0.0",
  "d3-time": "^1.0.0",
  "d3-scale": "^1.0.0",
  "d3-selection": "1.0.0"
}
```

As a reference you could look to see how other d3 plugins are configured, such as [Susie Lu's](https://github.com/susielu) plugin [d3.legend](https://github.com/susielu/d3-legend).

Answer (score 1):

With @clhenrick's gracious help, I got this working.  I did update my `index.js` file to only contain the `timeline` export.

I had to update `src/timeline.js` to:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';

var timeline = function() { <code> };
export default timeline;
```

If I tried to import the d3 packages individually (`d3-axis`, `d3-selection`, etc), then my `on("click")` events were getting a `Cannot read property 'sourceEvent' of null` error for the `d3.mouse(this)` call.

I had to update my `rollup.config.js` to:

```
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';

let pkg = require("./package.json");
let external = Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies);

export default {
    entry: 'index.js',
    dest: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'umd',
    moduleName: 'd3-timeline',
    external: external,
    plugins: [nodeResolve({ jsnext: true, main: true})]
};
```

When running `npm install` this creates a `umd` module that can be loaded in the browser and loads the `peerDependencies` section (which contains `d3`) from the `package.json` as external dependencies (which means they don't get bundled into my `d3-timeline.js`).

Then I copy the `d3-timeline.js` from the `build` directory into the `dist` directory to use in the example HTML files because `src/timeline.js` is no longer in a format that can be used directly by the browser.